# RecyclerViews in ScrollView not displaying data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerViews inside a `LinearLayout` and the `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` so I can scroll them together. I have tested this in a demo project and works as expected.

Now I move to another project I'm currently working on and I have two recyclerViews the first one displays some data stored in internal storage and the second one displays data I fetch from a network call.

The code for the UI is :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_failed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_downloaded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But what happens is that I see only the first list. I have tried removing the `ScrollView` from the XML and I can see the data, so it has nothing to do with not getting the data to display.

Should I change something on the code above? I have tried tinkering values of layout_height for both `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView` but it did not help.

Comment: I always hate to ask such question but are you sure your views are binding correctly in recyclerview adapter ?

Comment: @dex yes, I was using this code without any errors for a long time. The only changes are those in the xml file : add `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView`

Comment: can you please try removing scrollview as it is not required and make Linearlayout height as match_parent.

Comment: If I remove `ScrollView` then I won't have scrolling at all. The reason for adding `ScrollView` is to have both recyclerViews scroll together. Unless you are saying something else and I have not understand it.

Comment: oh then why don't you use nestedScrollView ?

Comment: Just tried with `NestedScrollView` but still the same. Only the first list displays data.

Comment: did you set the height of NestedScrollView as match_parent current it is wrap_content

Comment: Well I have just changed it and now it is working! :) Thanks. Would you like to add your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_failed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_downloaded"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```